# Intersection-Based Collision Detection which determines the side hit

Tags: java, algorithm, collision-detection

You might think this was already answered, but it wasn't. Because it cant really be answered just by checking the actual intersection at a certain time.

[image]

In the image, the "side hit" depends of the last position. if the rectangle is coming from above, then the side hit of the big rectangle was the bottom. but if the rectangle comes from the right, the side hit will be the right one.

All of this really bugs me, since i was able to implement a somewhat complex collision detection for my game's bullets, that is, fast objects, and i was thinking the simple collision would be the easiest. But since i actually have to respond, and not only detect, the simple collision algorithm becomes a pain.

My question is how to implement an actually functional and flawless collision algorithm which CAN depend on intersections but is accurate, like using the last position or some exterior resource to actually calculate the optimal answer. Of course this is causing me trouble only at the corners. But it can't cause trouble anywhere.

(Using the last position seems like the obvious answer but i don't know how to handle the information to reach an output, that is why I made the question, I tried but my brain hurts now)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to give an in depth answer, but the accepted answer to [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/how-do-i-handle-collision-detection-so-fast-objects-are-not-allowed-to-pass-thro) pretty much sums up what I was going to say. This is a common problem that people run into when first attempting basic collision detection. The solutions to this problem are more complex than you would think, and they essentially revolve around calculating the object's positions at the point of collision.

Edit: To figure out exactly what time the two objects collided you can do something like this: (not tested)

```
onCollide(obj1, obj2)
{
    t = 0; //parametric value to store when objects first collided
    // calculate when the obj1's left side collides with obj2's right side
    // parametric equation is obj1.left + obj1.vel.x * t = obj2.right + obj2.vel.x * t
    // solving for t: t = (obj1.left - obj2.right) / (obj2.vel.x - obj1.vel.x)
    // we take the minimum because that is when the first sides collided
    t = math.min(t, (obj1.left - obj2.right) / (obj2.vel.x - obj1.vel.x))
    t = math.min(t, (obj1.right - obj2.left) / (obj2.vel.x - obj1.vel.x))// repeat for other sides
    t = math.min(t, (obj1.top - obj2.bottom) / (obj2.vel.y - obj1.vel.y))
    t = math.min(t, (obj1.bottom - obj2.top) / (obj2.vel.y - obj1.vel.y))
}
```

Using this time you can rewind the entire simulation back if you want. Or you can just look at those two object's states. Instead of using the min function you can use an if statement and keep track of which two sides collided first. Keep in mind that this calculation doesn't keep track of multiple objects potentially colliding in that time step, but usually that is a valid approximation. Also keep in mind that you should avoid dividing by zero when two objects are traveling at the same speed in one dimension but not the other.

Comment: That post asks for anti-tunneling algorithms. In my case, im stating that colliding objects have intersection, that is, tunneling doesnt happen. And my point is that using an anti-tunneling algorithm is too expensive when i can actually check for the intersection, but to respond to the intersection i need at least to know which side was hit, which cant be known ONLY by the intersection.

Comment: If all you want to know is which side of the rectangle was hit, you can calculate the positions of the rectangles at the moment of collision. I'll edit my original post with general steps to do that.

Comment: I just told you that calculating the positions of the rectangle at the moment of collision is not enough to determine which side was hit. That is the whole point of this question. The side hit doesnt only depend on the exact collision moment, but it also depends of the previous position. The image gives a good example.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the moment of collision means. What is depicted in your diagram is not the moment of collision but at some point after. The moment of collision is the exact moment when the two rectangles first intersect. You can determine which side it hit by finding out the exact time two sides intersect given their velocities and taking the first sides to intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection test is never the way to make 'perfect' collision. The higher the speed, the lesser the possibility for a good callback or any callback at all. Use a physics engine like box2d or create your own (not recommended).

For intersection test on the sides, you can see the collided objects' bounds (rectangles) in relation to their sizes.

Comment: You missed my point, anti-tunneling collision algorithms end up being quite expensive and not needed in some particular cases, that is, when the objects size is big enough for its speed iteration to not mark an intersection. The point of this question is an algorithm that works when there is no tunneling, which is blocked simply by the game's logic. Therefore, speed isn't a problem.

Comment: In that case, how about line to line intersection test? http://keith-hair.net/blog/2008/08/08/line-to-polygon-intersection-data/

Comment: Also this - http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/12/14/how-to-make-a-2d-platform-game-part-2-collision-detection/